# Floating point error in system of 4 equations using Gaussian Elimination in Fortran 90

Tags: fortran, fortran90

This program is returning a `"floating point error: overflow"` with the following temperature values:

> 170
>   225
>   275
>   330
>   390
>   445
>   500
>   555
>   610
>   670
>   725
>   775
>   830
>   1100
>   1390
>   1670

Which is quite obvious, given the HUGE values that need to be raised up to the power 16 and then added.

This matrix represents a system of 4 equations that needs to be solved using Gaussian elimination for which have the remaining code ready.

```
Real Mat(4,4),Temp(10), Temp2(10),Sum

Do i=1,16
    Write(*,*)"enter Temperature value T",i
    Read (*,*) Temp(i)
End do

Do i=1,16
    Do j=1,16
        sum=0
        Do k=1,16
           if(i.GT.1)then
                l=(4*(i-1))+j
            elseif(i.eq.1)then
                l=i+j-1
            endif   
            Temp2(k)=Temp(k)**l
            sum=sum+Temp2(k)
        End do
        Mat(i,j)=Sum
    End do
End Do

Do I=1,4
  Write(*,*) (mat(I,J), j=1,4)
End do
 !this just forces the program to stay in the exe wind
    Read(*,*) sum
End
```

Comment: In the nested loop you have posted, you are potentially raising to much higher powers than 16, since for `i == j == 16`, you have `l == 76`. The value 1670^76 is too large for the usual default single precision `real(4)`, but not for double or quadruple precision. Also, as Vladimir proposes, please explicitly declare all your variables, even loop counters.

Comment: Oh, you are right, I did not try these large values and for temps around 100 it was still ok for single. But generally I don't know what  he wants to compute, so I did not examine the algorithm. (I suppose that the loops should have been only 1..4,1..4)

Comment: @Vladimir: Yes, I'm also not really sure what the asker was aiming at, but at least the code he posted should run fine with the appropriate array sizes and precision.

Answer (score 5):

Your array `Temp` is only 10 elements. You cannot read in 16 numbers. `Mat` is only `(4,4)` but you call it as `(i,j)` in loops `1..16` and `1..16`.

Also, add `implicit none`, I would not consider a program without that for marking from my students.

I recommend you to use a compiler with good debugging features and set the correct flags. I use `gfortran -g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -Wall`. `g95` is also good. Also commercial `NAG`, which even checks for undefined values at runtime..